# How to use FastAPI model class attributes as a schema fields

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am discovering the Python web framework FastAPI and I am asking if its possible to use the database model class attributes as a schema, because every time I need to hardcode my fields for the model classes as well as the pydantic classes??

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible if you're using an ORM, like https://tortoise.github.io/

Comment: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/ might be what you're looking for, a bridge between Pydantic models and the SQLAlchemy model. However, these two might differ in layout - i.e. you want the input/output schema to differ from your database model; SQLModel has a few mechanisms to handle that for you if necessary.

Comment: This [doc](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/) can help you if I understand correctly what you want.